# Python - why are my numbers not storing correctly

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to take in a string of numbers, such as:

```
1 2 3 4 55 33 15
```

and store them in a list as they appear so that I can operate on the items at each index in the list, but they aren't splitting and storing right. They store like:

```
1,2,3,4,5,5,3,3,1,5
```

which is not what I want. My current code is attached below. I thought they would store as:

```
1,2,3,4,5,55,33,15
```

I do convert them to ints later on and that works fine, this is just the part that I am stuck on.

```
numbersArrayTemp.append(userInput.readline().strip(' ').strip('\n'))


for item in numbersArrayTemp:
    print(item)
    Type = item.strip('\n')
    print(Type)
    j = item.replace(" ", '')

   numbersArrayString.extend(j)
```

Comment: You say you want to store those numbers in a list, and then you contradict yourself and say you want to store them like `1,2,3,4,5,55,33,15`. Which is it?

Comment: In a list, but as whole numbers, not split up where 55 is 5,5. There will be something in the above code that is making it not work properly but I can't see it.

Comment: Try `.split()` on the string!

Comment: Your code never splits the string, so of course it doesn't work.